# Not able to load and play an audio file in videojs-record while using audio only plugin?

Tags: vue.js, audio, vuejs3, videojs-record

### Description

I have 2 different components, one for Video one for Audio,
My Video component successfully plays the recorded Video, but My Audio does not play the audio only

almost a similar plugin for Video recording working the same way completely fine[image]

I am using a Mac M1 pro
Vue 3
"videojs-record": "^4.7.0"

here is my complete component code

```
<script setup>
/* eslint-disable */
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";
import "videojs-record/dist/css/videojs.record.css";
import videojs from "video.js";
import "webrtc-adapter";
import RecordRTC from "recordrtc";
import WaveSurfer from "wavesurfer.js";
import MicrophonePlugin from "wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.microphone.js";
WaveSurfer.microphone = MicrophonePlugin;
import Wavesurfer from "videojs-wavesurfer/dist/videojs.wavesurfer.js";
import videojs_wavesurfer_css from "videojs-wavesurfer/dist/css/videojs.wavesurfer.css?inline";
import Record from "videojs-record/dist/videojs.record.js";

const emit = defineEmits(['audio_recorded_data'])

const props = defineProps({
    "audio-recorded-data": {
        type: Object,
        required: false,
        default: {}
    },
    "is-reviewing": {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false,
        default: false
    },
})

const options = ref({
    controls: true,
    bigPlayButton: false,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    fluid: false,
    plugins: {
        wavesurfer: {
            backend: "WebAudio",
            waveColor: "#36393b",
            progressColor: "black",
            displayMilliseconds: true,
            debug: true,
            cursorWidth: 1,
            hideScrollbar: true,
            plugins: [
                // enable microphone plugin
                WaveSurfer.microphone.create({
                    bufferSize: 4096,
                    numberOfInputChannels: 1,
                    numberOfOutputChannels: 1,
                    constraints: {
                        video: false,
                        audio: true,
                    },
                }),
            ],
        },
        record: {
            audio: true,
            video: false,
            maxLength: 300,
            displayMilliseconds: false,
            debug: true,
        },
    },
});
const player = ref(null);
const playerWidth = ref("80%"); // Initial width
const playerHeight = ref("auto"); // Initial height
const recordedData = ref(false)
const recordingTime = ref(0);
onMounted(() => {
    // create player
    window.addEventListener("resize", setPlayerSize());

    setTimeout(() => {
        player.value = videojs("myAudio", options.value, function () {
            // print version information at startup
            var msg =
                "Using video.js " +
                videojs.VERSION +
                " with videojs-record " +
                videojs.getPluginVersion("record") +
                ", videojs-wavesurfer " +
                videojs.getPluginVersion("wavesurfer") +
                ", wavesurfer.js " +
                WaveSurfer.VERSION +
                " and recordrtc " +
                RecordRTC.version;
            videojs.log(msg);
        });

        // error handling
        player.value.on("deviceError", function () {
            console.log("device error:", player.value.deviceErrorCode);
        });

        player.value.on("error", function (element, error) {
            console.error(error);
        });

        // user clicked the record button and started recording
        player.value.on("startRecord", function () {
            recordedData.value = false
            console.log("started recording!");
        });

        // user completed recording and stream is available
        player.value.on("finishRecord", function () {
            recordedData.value = false
            // the blob object contains the recorded data that
            // can be downloaded by the user, stored on server etc.
            console.log("finished recording: ", player.value.recordedData);
            recordedData.value = player.value.recordedData
            emit('audio_recorded_data', recordedData.value)
        });

        player.value.on('progressRecord', function () {
            recordingTime.value = player.value.record().getDuration();
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (!props?.isReviewing && props?.audioRecordedData === undefined || Object.keys(props?.audioRecordedData).length === 0) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    player.value.record().getDevice();
                }, 500);
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    try {
                        const blob = new Blob([props?.audioRecordedData], { type: props?.audioRecordedData?.type });
                        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        // player.value.src({ type: props?.audioRecordedData?.type, src: blobUrl });
                        // player.value.play();

                        // Option 2: Create a new player instance (experiment with both)
                        const newPlayer = videojs("myAudio", options.value, function () {
                            this.src({ type: props?.audioRecordedData?.type, src: blobUrl });
                            this.play(); // Play the audio
                        });
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error setting audio source:', error);
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        }, 200);
    }, 100);
});

const formattedRecordingTime = computed(() => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(recordingTime.value / 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor(recordingTime.value % 60);
    return `0${minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? '0' : ''}${seconds}`;
})

const setPlayerSize = () => {
    // Adjust player size based on window size or other conditions
    // Example: Make the player width 80% of the window width and height 60% of the window height
    playerWidth.value = `${window.innerWidth * 100}px`;
    playerHeight.value = `${window.innerHeight * 0.55}px`;
};

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", setPlayerSize());
    if (player.value) {
        player.value.record().destroy();
    }
});

const recordingStarted = ref(false)
const startRecording = () => {
    player.value.record().start()
    emit('audio_recorded_data', false)
    recordingStarted.value = true
}
const stopRecording = () => {
    player.value.record().stop()
    recordingStarted.value = false

}
/* const resetRecording = () => {
    player.value.record().reset()
    recordingStarted.value = false
    recordedData.value = false
    recordedData.time = 0

} */
</script>
<template>
    <audio id="myAudio" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"></audio>
    <div class="px-20">
        <div class="flex justify-center font-extrabold md:font-bold sm:font-semibold sm:text-xl md:text-2xl text-3xl">
            <!-- Use a combination of flexible and fixed width for the time ticker container -->
            <div class="w-full md:w-auto md:max-w-xs"> <!-- Adjust the max width as needed -->
                <div class="w-60 text-center">
                    <h1 class="blue text-center">{{ formattedRecordingTime }}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center text-center" v-if="!props?.isReviewing">
            <div class="bg-blue-light px-8 py-3 rounded-full" v-if="!recordingStarted">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <button class="flex items-center gap-2" @click="startRecording">
                        <span>
                            <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#C9C9C9" stroke-width="0.336">
                                <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0" />
                                <g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
                                    <path
                                        d="M21.4086 9.35258C23.5305 10.5065 23.5305 13.4935 21.4086 14.6474L8.59662 21.6145C6.53435 22.736 4 21.2763 4 18.9671L4 5.0329C4 2.72368 6.53435 1.26402 8.59661 2.38548L21.4086 9.35258Z"
                                        fill="#1E346F" />
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <span class="text-blue"> Start </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-blue-light px-3 py-3 rounded-full" v-if="recordingStarted">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <button class="flex items-center gap-2" @click="stopRecording">
                        <span>
                            <svg width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24.00 24.00" fill="none"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#C9C9C9" stroke-width="0.336">
                                <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0" />
                                <g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
                                    <path
                                        d="M2 6C2 4.11438 2 3.17157 2.58579 2.58579C3.17157 2 4.11438 2 6 2C7.88562 2 8.82843 2 9.41421 2.58579C10 3.17157 10 4.11438 10 6V18C10 19.8856 10 20.8284 9.41421 21.4142C8.82843 22 7.88562 22 6 22C4.11438 22 3.17157 22 2.58579 21.4142C2 20.8284 2 19.8856 2 18V6Z"
                                        fill="#1E346F" />
                                    <path
                                        d="M14 6C14 4.11438 14 3.17157 14.5858 2.58579C15.1716 2 16.1144 2 18 2C19.8856 2 20.8284 2 21.4142 2.58579C22 3.17157 22 4.11438 22 6V18C22 19.8856 22 20.8284 21.4142 21.4142C20.8284 22 19.8856 22 18 22C16.1144 22 15.1716 22 14.5858 21.4142C14 20.8284 14 19.8856 14 18V6Z"
                                        fill="#1E346F" />
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* change player background color */
#myAudio {
    background-color: #9fd6ba;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.audio-player-container {
    /* Add additional styling for the container if needed */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

:deep(.vjs-control-bar) {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px !important;
}</style>
```